# How can I find a point on a rotated square that has a set y value?

Tags: trigonometry, circles, rotations

I have this square that is rotating inside the circle.
[image]
I want the horizontal line on the left to always be on the edge of the rotating square (where the green point is), but it will be constantly rotating, so can I calculate the point where the line will first meet the square based on the angle and side length?
[Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mkttohqgdz)

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear which is the "line on the left"? is it the horizontal green line? Do you want to extend it to the green point? If that is the case, what you want is the position of the point on the square at $y=y_{center}$ and $x<x_{center}$ as a function of the rotation angle. Do I get it right?

Comment: So given the fixed horizontal green line that would intersect the center of a rotating square you want to identify the point where the line would first meet the square?

Comment: Yes, the horizontal line is what I meant, and yes I want to identify the point point where the line would first meet the square. Does anyone know how to do that? (Editing my question also)

Comment: When the angle is zero is the square perpendicular to both axes?

Comment: if you mean it is flat and not rotated, Yes, the desmos has an angle slider d, (Desmos in an edit, you may need to refresh) that you can drag to see the angle EDIT d is a infinite playback var, not a slider

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!
[image: Image of desmos]
[Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2ceioegdyh)

I used point slope form line + regressions to get the intercept. Thanks for all the help! :)

All I need to do now is use only the two points that are on the right side, but I can figure that out!

Answer (score 0):

Well, let see... one corner of the square is $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ and the other corner is $(\cos(\theta + 90), \sin (\theta +90))=(\sin \theta, -\cos \theta)$.

Those two points are on a line with slope $\frac {\sin \theta + \cos\theta}{\cos \theta - \sin \theta}$.

And that should do it.... we have the slope of a line, we have two points of the line so we can make the equation for the line and we can calculate the $x$ intercept from that.

Comment: You would need to calculate the intersections with the other sides and choose the one with the $x$ in the range $[x_{center}-R,x_{center}]$

Comment: Can you show that in a desmos? I don't quite understand. My desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mkttohqgdz